# marker style for each data series

Tags: octave

Given a matrix representing 3 data series, e.g.

```
data = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9]
```

I would like to use a different marker/line style per each series, without specifying explicitly each series in the arguments. Is that possible?

In other words, I am aware of this method:

```
plot(data(:,1), "x-", data(:,2), "+-", data(:,3), "o-")
```

and it produces exactly the result I desire, but specifying each different column and its associated style is unpractical if I have many columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that is possible to specify styles for each column in this way:

```
plot(data, ["x-"; "+-"; "o-"])
```

I was stuck because I tried using commas instead of semicolons, and it didn't work:

```
plot(data, ["x-", "+-", "o-"]) % will consider only "o-"
```